# Вывод постов по их id

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести определённые посты по их id? Делаю так:

```
$recent = new WP_Query(['p' => 10207]);
```

Выводит только одну, так как указал один id. Делаю так:

```
$recent = new WP_Query(['p' => [10207, 10117]]);
```

Происходит ошибка запроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p принимает только одно число. Используйте post__in:

```
$recent = new WP_Query( 
    array( 'post__in' => array( 10207, 10117 ) ) 
);
```

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!